# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "jquery" though true path

Tags: reactjs

Here I am require jquery module but it cant be. I spent hours on it I think much complicated.[image]

Left side `react` can be required,but `jquery` can not.

Comment: you can see on left hand side.

Comment: hello man when i require bootstrap this error remains :(

Comment: Have you tried re-installing all dependencies?

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: dude...this may be solved but this same error come while including bootstrap(title error for bootstrap)..can you help on it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I had this same issue in my react app:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery'
```

What was happening is I had my jquery files in my bower_components, but I didn't have it correctly included in my package.json, I ran:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm run
```